# java read date from json

Tags: java, json, date, long-integer

Hi I'm trying to read date from a JSON object. Date is written to the JSON as UTC milliseconds, but when I try to read it, informamtion is lost. JSON is giving the number

```
"time":1526438700000
```

and

```
int value = jsonObj.getInt("time")
```

returns a different value. Could there be information loss converting `long` to `int`?

I am using the `javax.json` implementation. `jsonObj` is an object I get from a `JsonArray`. I don't think there's a `getLong` method. I tried casting to `long`, declaring value as `long`, same result. I think the problem is `getInt()`?

Comment: The number `1526438700000` is too large to fit in a 32-bit `int`. Use a 64-bit `long` instead.

Comment: I don't think there's a getLong() method. I tried casting to long, declaring value as long same result. I think the problem is getInt()?

Comment: What is `jsonObj`? What JSON API / library are you using?

Comment: jsonObj is an object I get from a JsonArray. I am using the javax,json implementation

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution using your library

Comment: @vathan Welcome to Stack Overflow. It’s great that you are so responsive and answer the questions in the comments. Still better, do that by editing your question (use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50351098/edit) link) and adding all information there so everything is in one place (then you may ping the author of the comment and tell you’ve done so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number is bigger than the [maximum value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE) that could be hold in an int (MAX_VALUE = 2147483647)

Try to get it as a long, as the max value is way bigger (MAX_VALUE = 9223372036854775807L).

With the javax.json library, you can get the long value through [`getJsonNumber`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getJsonNumber-java.lang.String-) method

```
jsonObj.getJsonNumber("time").longValue();
```